# continuous functions on unit circle -- group isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, continuity

> Let $G$ be the additive group of continuous real-valued functions on the unit circle $S^{1}$, let $H$ be its subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$-valued functions, and let $\tilde{G}$ be the additive group of continuous functions on $S^{1}$ with values in $S^{1}$.

Does there exist an isomorphism of groups $G/H \cong \tilde{G}$?

Thanks for helping, and sorry for not showing any effort but I feel like this is a one-step-solution if there does not exist such an isomorphism, which is what I hope for.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Yes I am.

Comment: $G$ is the additive group of  continuous real-valued functions on the unit circle , $H$ is the additive subgroup of constant $\mathbb{Z}$-valued functions on the unit circle. ? hence $H \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $G / H = (S^1 \to \mathbb{R}) / (S^1 \to \mathbb{Z}) \cong S^1 \to (\mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z})$ (many abuses of notation but you see what I mean)

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not isomorphic.  One way to see this is that for any $a\in G$, there exists $b\in G$ such that $b^2=a$ (just define $b(x)=a(x)/2$).  It follows that the same is true in any quotient of $G$, and in particular in $G/H$.

On the other hand, $\tilde{G}$ does not have this property.  For instance, the identity map $S^1\to S^1$ cannot be written as the square of any continuous map $S^1\to S^1$: this is just the fact that it is impossible to continuously define a square root for every unit complex number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't quite understand how you can argue with multiplications since the isomorphism is one of additive groups. Moreover, wouldn't the multiplication on $G$ be defined pointwise, i.e. $(bc)(x)=b(x)c(x)$, and thus I don't see how $b^2=a$ for $b$ with $b(x)=a(x)/2$. Some clarification would be helpful.

Comment: If you define the group structure on $G$ by pointwise multiplication, it's not a group, because any function that takes the value $0$ somewhere has no inverse.  The only obvious group structure is pointwise addition.  On the other hand, the only obvious group structure on $\tilde{G}$ is pointwise multiplication (where you think of $S^1$ as the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$).